# React | Ant Design Select 'Open' api customization

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, I use Ant design. I Try to get the autocomplete in select by means of modification the **select open Api**. I modify the choose **api value of open at a specific situation** by using the boolean state value.

My problem is that when I type to select textbox and the **enter text length is larger than 2, I get the option**, which works OK, but when I try to delete characters in the textbox one by one and the enter text length is 3, **when I try to delete one character but the entire text in the text box is cleared** . Please see the code below, as well as a link to an online example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-already-selected-antd-4-20-5-forked-84mpxj?file=/demo.js

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const OPTIONS = [
  "Apples",
  "Nails",
  "Bananas",
  "Helicopters",
  "Appless",
  "Nailss",
  "Bananass",
  "Helicoptesrs",
  "Applefs",
  "Naigls",
  "Banafnas",
  "Heldicopters"
];

class SelectWithHiddenSelectedOptions extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: [],
    show: false
  };

  handleChange = (selectedItems) => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
    if (selectedItems.length > 2) {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }
  };

  handleSearch = (val) => {
    if (val.length > 2) {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;

    const filteredOptions = OPTIONS.filter((o) => !selectedItems.includes(o));
    return (
      <Select
        showSearch
        placeholder="Inserted are removed"
        open={this.state.show}
        value={selectedItems}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        // onSearch={this.handleChange}
        onSearch={(val) => this.handleChange(val)}
      >
        {filteredOptions.map((item) => (
          <Select.Option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </Select.Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    );
  }
}

export default () => <SelectWithHiddenSelectedOptions />;
```

Comment: There may be some kind of event, which is making this to happen. I think antd has an event to empty the value when the dropdown closes or hides

Comment: Hi there, normally handleChange is used just for notify and set the value, like Formik or some state variable. In your situation, you may use onKeyPress event to handle text length and other logics.